# Why does my python dict become unordered?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, data-modeling

I am using this to produce a plot of % of names starting with a certain letter over a span of years. When plotting (and printing) my diction (letter_d) the keys are disordered rather than being sequential like how they are added to the dict. Is there a way to fix this, I believe I am adding them to the dict in a sequential order. If not is there a way I can create connect the dots of my scatter plot in order to simulate the correct line plot?

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

start = 1880
stop = 1890
x = []
years = range(start, stop +1)
print years
letter_d = {}
year_d = {}
alphabet = ['Z']#,'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

for i in alphabet:
    letter_d[i] = 0

for year in years:
    filename = 'yob' + str(year) + '.txt'
    z = open(filename)      
    year_d[int(year)] = 0
    letter_d[i] = year_d
    c = 0
    d = 0
    for line in z:
        y = line.strip().split(',')
        y.remove(y[1])
        c += int(y[1])
        if i in y[0]:
            d += int(y[1])
        year_d[year] = float(d)/float(c)            
        #x.append(y)
#print year_d
print year_d.keys()
plt.plot(year_d.keys(), year_d.values())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Python dictionaries are **always** unordered.

Comment: Use `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Answer (score 6):

Python dictionaries are *always* unordered.

In your case, you don't need a dictionary *at all*. Use two lists; one is the `years` list you already produced from a range, the other for the calculated values:

```
year_values = []

for year in years:
    # ...
    year_values.append(float(d)/float(c))

plt.plot(years, year_values)
```

Comment: That makes my work much clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said dictionaries are unordered.
To keep your code, there is a way to display your plot sorted.
Sorting dictionary keys.

Look

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    year_d = {"5": 'b', "3": 'c', "4": 'z', "1":'a'}
    print year_d.keys()
    keys = map(int, year_d.keys())
    keys = map(keys.sort(), keys)
    print keys
```

original:
['1', '3', '5', '4']
sorted:
[1, 3, 4, 5]